# Can I force or induce iOS 14 App Tracking Transparency authorization?

Tags: ios, ios14, ios-permissions, apptrackingtransparency

Since iOS 14, my app ad revenue has been drastically reduced due to Apple's new privacy policy. So I wanted to somehow force or induce users to enable ATT authorization. Can I do something below?

- Force users to enable it unless they won't be able to use the app
- Induce users by letting them know there could be more ads if they don't enable ATT authorization.

Comment: You have no way of forcing them. Imo the best you can do is try to educate them inside your app before requesting permission. Ex "here's why we need ATT Authorization". If you ask them nicely, some users will say yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FAQ section of the Apples ["User privacy and data use"-website](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/user-privacy-and-data-use/) says:

> Can I gate functionality on agreeing to allow tracking, or incentivize
> users to agree to allow tracking in the app tracking transparency
> prompt?
>
> No, per the [App Store Review Guidelines: 3.2.2 (vi)](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#unacceptable).

This means that your app would probably  be rejected by Apple if you were to use one of the methods you suggested.

Explain to your users why you need the ATT permission before you request the authorization - some users will grant the authorization.